# DRYing out scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

Beginner rubyist here. Im defining the following scopes and I have a strong feeling that i could do this in a much DRYier way. Any thoughts on how to do this in a less repetitive way?

```
scope :end_during, ->(new_start_time, new_end_time) do
  if (!new_start_time.nil?) && (!new_end_time.nil?)
    where('end_time > ? AND end_time < ?', new_start_time, new_end_time)
  else
    return nil
  end
end

scope :start_during, ->(new_start_time, new_end_time) do
  if (!new_start_time.nil?) && (!new_end_time.nil?)
    where('start_time > ? AND start_time < ?', new_start_time, new_end_time)
  else
    return nil
  end
end

scope :happening_during, ->(new_start_time, new_end_time) do
  if (!new_start_time.nil?) && (!new_end_time.nil?)
    where('start_time > ? AND end_time < ?', new_start_time, new_end_time)
  else
    return nil
  end 
end

scope :enveloping, ->(new_start_time, new_end_time) do
  if (!new_start_time.nil?) && (!new_end_time.nil?)
    where('start_time < ? AND end_time > ?', new_start_time, new_end_time)
  else
    return nil
  end
end

scope :identical, ->(new_start_time, new_end_time) do
  if (!new_start_time.nil?) && (!new_end_time.nil?)
    where('start_time = ? AND end_time = ?', new_start_time, new_end_time)
  else
    return nil
  end
end
```

This is how they are used:

```
def overlaps
  overlapping_bookings = [ 
    subject.bookings.end_during(start_time, end_time),
    subject.bookings.start_during(start_time, end_time),
    subject.bookings.happening_during(start_time, end_time),
    subject.bookings.enveloping(start_time, end_time),
    subject.bookings.identical(start_time, end_time)
  ].flatten

 overlapping_bookings.delete self
 if overlapping_bookings.any?
   errors.add(:base, 'Slot has already been booked')
 end
end
```

Comment: I added a Rails tag since you're asking about Rails as much as Ruby

Comment: Just to confirm, are `start_during` and `happening_during` supposed to be identical?

Comment: Looks like even `enveloping` is the same as `start_during` and `happening_during`. Not sure if this is an illustrative example? Perhaps `scope_chaining` is what you are looking for?

Comment: The column names and comparisons differ.  I got caught by that too.

Comment: They are different. Slightly, but different. Thats why I can't get my head around how to make this in a simpler manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just factor the common stuff into another scope, which you then invoke with the right parameters from your individual scopes:

```
scope :time_constraint, ->(c1, f1, c2, f2) do
  return nil unless f1 && f2
  where "%s ? AND %s ?" % [c1, c2], f1, f2
end

scope :end_during,       ->(start_time, end_time) { time_constraint "end_time >",   start_time, "end_time <",   end_time }
scope :start_during,     ->(start_time, end_time) { time_constraint "start_time >", start_time, "start_time <", end_time }
scope :happening_during, ->(start_time, end_time) { time_constraint "start_time >", start_time, "end_time <",   end_time }
scope :enveloping,       ->(start_time, end_time) { time_constraint "start_time <", start_time, "end_time >",   end_time }
scope :enveloping,       ->(start_time, end_time) { time_constraint "start_time =", start_time, "end_time =",   end_time }
```

It doesn't read too badly, either.